# Show that the unit circle minus a point is connected (without using path connectedness)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

I am trying to show that the closed unit interval $I = [0,1]$ is not homeomorphic to $S^1$ using the notion of connectedness (and not the notion of path connectedness).

A proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1776895/show-that-the-circle-x-y-%E2%88%88-r2-x2-y2-1-is-not-homeomorphic-to-th) shows that the two are not homeomorphic because, if $f: I \to S^1$ were a homeomorphism, then a contradiction arises when we restrict the domain of $f$ to $I \setminus \{a\}$. The contradiction comes from the fact that $I \setminus \{a\}$ is disconnected whereas $S^1 \setminus \{p\}$ is connected, for any point $a \in (0,1)$ (that is, any interior point $a$) and $f(a) = p$.

But I can't figure out how to show that $S^1 \setminus \{p\}$ is connected using just the definition of connectedness.

The definition of connectedness that I have is the following, from Willard:

> A space $X$ is disconnected iff there are disjoint nonempty open sets
> $H$ and $K$ in $X$ such that $X = H \cup K$. When no such
> disconnection exists, $X$ is connected.

Equivalently, a disconnection could be made from two disjoint, nonempty closed sets (sometimes this construction seems easier, depending on the topology).

Again, equivalently, we can say that a space $X$ is disconnected iff there exists a proper clopen (both closed and open) subset of $X$.

I've tried to show that, if we assume $S^1 \setminus \{p\}$ is disconnected then we get some contradiction, but I haven't had any luck.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f:I\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^1$ is a homeomorphism. Pick a point $x\in I\backslash \{0,1\}$. Denote the point this point is mapped to by N. We get that $I\backslash \{ x\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1 \backslash \{N\}$. However, via sterographic projection, $\mathbb{S}^1\backslash \{N\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore $\mathbb{S}^1\backslash \{N\}$ is connected. Since $I\backslash \{x\}$ is disconnected, $I$ and $\mathbb{S}^1$ cannot be homeomorphic.

Comment: Note that $I\setminus\{x\}$ is connected if $x\in\{0,1\}$ (so be careful with how you choose $x$...)

Comment: How do we guarantee that the point mapped to the North Pole (by which I guess you mean the point (0,1)) isn’t one of the end points of $I$? In this case $I \setminus \{x\}$ would also be connected, so there’s no contradiction. (I also don’t actually know how stereographic projection works, so if you might be able to explain that as well, that would be appreciated).

Comment: @Tyrone fixed, you’re right.

Comment: @TuringTester69, sure, when I have time, I’ll elaborate on stereographic projection.

Comment: @Moe just wanted to bump this - could you please explicitly denote what the homeomorphism between $\mathbb{S}^1 \setminus \{N\}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is?